# Is it possible to reference Cells via Cells in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a spreadsheet i'm trying to fix up, on the final page i want it to gather totals, so far this is the structure

```
Month | Year | Month Start | Month End | Month Total
```

how this supposed to work is that the user enters the month and year then inputs the start and end rows (Month Start and End) of another page, this other page will contain records of transactions made with each transaction being a separate row, this can mean one month can have 5 transaction while another may have 50

i'm making the assumption that the user doesn't now how to reference data from another sheet so how i want to try and implement it so that they add the row numbers to Month Start and End and Month Total will generate the formula

---

eg.

```
Month Start = 4 

Month End = 6

Formula Generated in Month Total = "=SUM(Transactions!E4:E6)"
```

---

if the user changes Month End to 9, the formula generated above will change the E6 part to E9, like i said above, each row in the Transactions sheet is a transaction and there can be variable number of transactions a month

what i am asking is if it is possible to references cells like this

Comment: If you're going to be returning a month total, why don't you just use the sumif or sumifs functions?

Comment: i did think about that however SUMIF works much like SUM but with the added functionality of an IF Statement, it still runs into the problem from the fact that the formula doesn't know the start or end rows, only the column

Comment: Aren't the start and end rows where the month start and end? Is there a date column there?

Comment: yes and yes, i see where your coming from but i would still need to something like =SUMIF(Transactions!A4:A999,[MONTH FIELD],Transactions!E4:E999) (SOMIFS if i checked both month and year), i could change the 999 to some stupidly huge number but i rather it be adaptive to the size that's being used, plus also it's best to assume that the user is lazy, by having it so the user sets the start and end rows they also may pick up any errors made in the data instead of relying solely on the output

Comment: Two things could prevent having to extend the range. 1. Convert range to table, then use table references. 2. Dynamic named ranges, which will count the number of rows for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OFFSET` function to generate offsets from a starting point.

Assuming your layout is like this:

```
  A      B      C      D    E
1 Year   Month  Start  End  Total
2 2012   Jan    4      9    =sum(...)
```

The total column (cell E2) could have the formula:
`=SUM(OFFSET(Transactions!E1,C2-1,0,(D2-C2)+1))`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [INDIRECT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx)

Comment: INDIRECT spits out some problems when i use it for trying to reference another sheet however i do have other problems which this syntax can resolve so thank you none the less

Comment: @memor-x INDIRECT should work fine with other sheets - are you remembering to add `'`' if needed? ie `'sheet name'`. OFFSET is useful for repetitive layouts but INDIRECT is much more versatile. +1

Comment: The trick I use with repetitive layouts and `INDIRECT` is to have a hidden row/column which defines the location of information you are looking up.  This makes it a lot easier to maintain if cell addresses change since you do not need to hand edit formulas.